# Spring JPA (MariaDB) Is it possible to use multiple non-primary keys as foreign keys?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, mariadb, foreign-keys

```
A parent table:
int aTableId; (key)
String type;
String category;


B child table:
int bTableId; (key)
String title;
String type;
String category;
```

What I want to do is make the "combination" of type and category existing in table A as a foreign key to the combination of type and category in table B.

in a formula
a.type == b.type && a.category == b.category
must be satisfied to insert into table B.

Let me explain it again

```
A parent table
1. type : food, category : fruit
2. type: food, category: vegetables
3. type : person, category : head
```

If such a combination exists in A parent table,

```
food - fruit
food - vegetables
person - head
```

The above combination is
It is possible to insert into table B, but

```
person - fruit
person - vegetables
food - head
```

This combination is not possible.

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  aTableId INT PRIMARY KEY,
  type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  category VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (type, category)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  bTableId INT PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  category VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (type, category) REFERENCES parent(type, category)
);
```

You can define a foreign key that references a secondary candidate key of the parent table. You should make that key a reliable candidate key: it should be unique and NOT NULL, so each reference in the child table is guaranteed to reference only one row in the parent table.

The unique key and the foreign key that references it can have multiple columns. The foreign key must have the same number and types of columns as the candidate key it references.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I've seen similar answers when searching other questions for troubleshooting.


But I would like to know how to apply that solution using JPA.

How can I do it via JPA without constraining the table directly?

Comment: I don't use JPA, but in general you can't use application code (including frameworks like JPA) to do the same thing that constraints can do. This is true regardless of language or framework.